# Changing directory name to desktop in Uipath

Tags: directory, desktop, uipath

I need assistance, how would I change the directory name from `download` to `C:\Users\sesethu.faku\Desktop\assetManagementFiles` to save files downloaded?

[image: Variable screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

your path would look like `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/assetManagementFiles"`

Comment: @veben, I actually think it does provide an answer to the question asked. Question author wanted to know how to set a path variable so it would look to a specific folder in user directory.